# How to check Docker Swarm resources reservation via cli

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I introduced Docker Swarm resources limit on a cluster (24 GB RAM and 12 VCPUs) and specified services limits with the following configurations:

```
  redis:
    image: redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        reservations:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 300m
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Now the problem is that I get the error `no suitable node (insufficient resources on 3 nodes)` and I can't understand what resources are over and where exactly. Is there a way to understand resource reservation overall?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some script to get the reservation in terms of memory and CPU by service:

```bash
docker service ls --format '{{ .ID }}' \
  | xargs docker service ps --format '{{ .ID }}\t{{ .DesiredState }}\t{{ .Name }}\t{{ .Node }}' \
  | grep Running \
  | awk -F'\t' '{split($3, array, ".");printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,array[1],$4);}' \
  | awk -F'\t' '{printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t",$1,$2,$3); system("docker service inspect --format \" BYTE[{{ .Spec.TaskTemplate.Resources.Reservations.MemoryBytes }}]\tCPU[{{ .Spec.TaskTemplate.Resources.Reservations.NanoCPUs }}]\" " $2); printf("//////////")}' \
  | sed 's/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\//\n/g' \
  | column -t -s $'\t'
```

If your service does not define a memory or CPU reservation, you will see `Status: Template parsing error: template: :1:14: executing "" at <.Spec.TaskTemplate.Resources.Reservations.MemoryBytes>: nil pointer evaluating *swarm.Resources.MemoryBytes, Code: 1`, error that you can safely ignore.

Here is some result :

```
Status: Template parsing error: template: :1:14: executing "" at <.Spec.TaskTemplate.Resources.Reservations.MemoryBytes>: nil pointer evaluating *swarm.Resources.MemoryBytes, Code: 1
Status: Template parsing error: template: :1:14: executing "" at <.Spec.TaskTemplate.Resources.Reservations.MemoryBytes>: nil pointer evaluating *swarm.Resources.MemoryBytes, Code: 1
Status: Template parsing error: template: :1:14: executing "" at <.Spec.TaskTemplate.Resources.Reservations.MemoryBytes>: nil pointer evaluating *swarm.Resources.MemoryBytes, Code: 1
mfqvby9sl2ak  validation-staf_delete-files-worker                node02.host.com         
jvxr385qjj    validation-staf_lta-product-zip-extraction-worker  node02.host.com         
i3gebgj8pe    validation-staf_lta-sip-generator-worker           node01.host.com         
4rli5dp0xv    validation-staf_rs-access-instance                 node01.host.com          BYTE[536870912]   CPU[250000000]
z50pnst1      validation-staf_rs-access-project                  node01.host.com          BYTE[536870912]   CPU[250000000]
rc9wdr1cs3    validation-staf_rs-admin-instance                  node02.host.com          BYTE[536870912]   CPU[500000000]
wd5kd4869tbj  validation-staf_rs-admin                           node02.host.com          BYTE[805306368]   CPU[500000000]
ihqyvsyr6yuc  validation-staf_rs-authentication                  node02.host.com          BYTE[268435456]   CPU[250000000]
htp0qm3q2z    validation-staf_rs-catalog                         node01.host.com          BYTE[1073741824]  CPU[1000000000]
gjn6vzlnap    validation-staf_rs-config                          node01.host.com          BYTE[134217728]   CPU[250000000]
qnub9gucv1tz  validation-staf_rs-dam                             node02.host.com          BYTE[1073741824]  CPU[1000000000]
of6qnmg2vj5b  validation-staf_rs-dataprovider                    node02.host.com          BYTE[1073741824]  CPU[500000000]
maf2yoijqc    validation-staf_rs-delivery                        node01.host.com          BYTE[536870912]   CPU[500000000]
xnxqub8930lv  validation-staf_rs-elasticsearch                   node02.host.com          BYTE[2097152000]  CPU[500000000]
i35pqgdzr45x  validation-staf_rs-fem                             node01.host.com          BYTE[1073741824]  CPU[1000000000]
qx87kc3i90    validation-staf_rs-front                           node02.host.com          BYTE[67108864]    CPU[100000000]
v0w4ncbmg2lk  validation-staf_rs-front                           node02.host.com          BYTE[67108864]    CPU[100000000]
x816mlmumhaz  validation-staf_rs-front                           node01.host.com          BYTE[67108864]    CPU[100000000]
qhcf5fzw9evv  validation-staf_rs-gateway                         node02.host.com          BYTE[268435456]   CPU[250000000]
1zdmwdremdvv  validation-staf_rs-ingest                          node02.host.com          BYTE[1073741824]  CPU[1000000000]
lfkr420ksopo  validation-staf_rs-kibana                          node01.host.com          BYTE[838860800]   CPU[500000000]
```

Then I use Excel to sum by node host and get this kind of information :
[image: memory by node]

Memory must be devide by 10^9 to get Gb
And (nano)CPU by 10^9 to get CPU